# Angular js Controller data not showing view page while using ui-router

Tags: angularjs

I have two controller profileCtrl and todayCtrl where i use ui-router in todayctrl. My today.js page is like this

```
var app = angular.module("Today",['ui.router]);    
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1    
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");
  //
  // Now set up the states
      $stateProvider
    .state('profile', {
      url: "/?id",
      templateUrl: 'profile.html',
      controller: function($scope,$stateParams,$http) {
          var user_id = $stateParams.id;
           $http.get('index.php?r=profile/user-profile&user_id='+user_id
//this is where my data will come from my php controller and i have data      here.
            ).success(function(data){

                $scope.profile = data;

            });
      }
    })
});

 app.controller("TodayCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    //some 
});
```

but my templateUrl is link for view page is

```
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="profileCtrl">
    {{profile}}
 <div>
```

if i put ng-controller as todayCtrl i get data.But what i need is profileCtrl.
Can somebody suggest me how can i use profileCtrl because i have other controller function in profileCtrl.

Comment: You might have to have `ng-app` match the name of your module. So `ng-app="Today"`. And `TodayCtrl` doesn't seem to be in the same module.

Comment: sorry my view page is                                                                                                   <div ng-app="profile" ng-controller="profileCtrl">
    {{profile}}
 <div>